# Probability that the sum of two elements in a set is divisible by 3.

Tags: combinatorics

Select 2 integers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. What is the probability that their sum is divisible by 3? I am assuming this is without replacement although this is not explicitly stated.

My answer: There are $\binom{8}{2}$ ways of selecting two elements. Only 6 of these pairs $(1,2), (4,5), (4,2), (7,8),(3,6), (2,7) $ are divisible by 3. Thus $P=6/\binom{8}{2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: What about (2,7)?  Make sure you are getting all of them.

Comment: Yeah, you missed a few pairs, but otherwise your reasoning is sound.

Comment: Also, (1,3) is a dud.

Comment: Given that I have missed quite a few pairs..is there a combinatorial approach to finding all pairs whose sum is divisible by 3?

Comment: @user98577 Andre's answer gives a combinatorial approach.

Answer (score 3):

We can make an explicit list and count. Or else note that there are $2$ numbers that have remainder $0$ on division by $3$ (list A) plus three numbers that have remainder $1$ (list B), plus three numbers that have remainder $2$ (list C). We must select $2$ numbers from list A ($1$ way) or $1$ each from lists B and C  ($3\times 3$ ways). The total is $10$. Divide by $\binom{8}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The possible pairs are $(1,2), (1,5),(1,8),(2,4),(2,7),(3,6),(4,5),(4,8),(5,7)$and $(7,8)$ thus there are 10 possible pairs out of 28 pairs. So the probability of the sum is divisible by 3 is 0.357

Answer (score 0):

Numbers can be classified as $3n$, $3n+1$, $3n+2$. Now the sum will be divisible by $3$ only if the pair is $(3n,3n)$ or $(3n+1,3n+2)$.

Digits of type: $3n = (3,6)$; type $3n+1= (1,4,7)$; type $3n+2 = (2,5,8)$. So the number of possible would be $1 + 3\cdot 3 = 10$. $\text{Total probability} = 10/28$.